# PhpStorm ToDo's not working on Mac OSX 10.15

Tags: phpstorm, todo

I cannot get PhpStorm 2020 to see the todo's. I even tried changing the regex but that did not work. Does anyone know how to to fix this?

I am using a mac with OSX 10.15.

Answer (score 0):

If the directories in your project are marked orange, they are excluded.
This can happen if you are using iCloud and the combination of the PHPStorm IDE not picking up all directories.

To solve this go to PHPStorm -> Preferences -> Directories -> then on the right hit "+ Add Content Root" and add the base of your project.

It will now turn all those directories into non-excluded ones and force a re-index. Now Todo's should appear in the toolbar.